# Google Merchant throws warning "Unrecognized attribute"

Tags: merchant-account

I'm facing an issue I can not explain :

When I'm uploading a feed to Google Merchant in an other language than English, the reports tells me there is many "Unrecognized attribute" that should be valid, like **title**, **link**, **description**, **gtin**, etc.

In fact, all attributes are considered warning from Google.
But the issue only occurs if it's not in english so my feed seems correct.

What is wrong? Do you have any ideas?

Thank for your help.

Here's a dump of my export (strimed to one product) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Google Shopping export for PrestaShop</title>
<item>
<g:id xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">12345</g:id>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Basic title ]]>
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.example.com/test
]]>
</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[
This is a basic product
]]>
</description>
<g:quantity xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">39</g:quantity>
<g:availability xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<![CDATA[ in stock ]]>
</g:availability>
<g:price xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">8.54 EUR</g:price>
<g:product_type xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<![CDATA[ Ofertas > Ofertas ]]>
</g:product_type>
<g:google_product_category xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<![CDATA[
Alimentaci&oacute;n, bebida y tabaco &gt; Bebidas &gt; Vino
]]>
</g:google_product_category>
<g:shipping_weight xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">1.4 kg</g:shipping_weight>
<g:online_only xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">n</g:online_only>
<g:condition xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">new</g:condition>
<g:brand xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">Angove Family Winemakers</g:brand>
<g:mpn xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">23500023</g:mpn>
<g:gtin xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"/>
<identifier_exists>FALSE</identifier_exists>
<g:image_link xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<![CDATA[
http://example.com/test/images/1.jpg
]]>
</g:image_link>
<g:shipping xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<g:country>ES</g:country>
<g:service>
<![CDATA[ ENVIALIA-72H ]]>
</g:service>
<g:price>24.2 EUR</g:price>
</g:shipping>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Show some of your feed here. Both the one that works and the one that doesn't. Also - try to go back to basic with the feed that doesn't work; so include only a single product - and see if that one fails. If it does not work, you have a much simpler feed to debug and share with us.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are uploading this as XML.

Are you encoding correctly your xml?

If you're submitting an XML file that uses either Latin-1 or UTF-16 encoding, please make sure you specify this information in your XML file. To do this, please change the first line of your data feed from  to:

For Latin-1: 
     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

For UTF-16: 
     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`

I read this from here:
https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160079

Also, have you tried to use a XML escape tool? Such as http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the feed is already in UTF-8. I added an output of the xml in order to give more details.

Comment: @CyrilN. Thanks for your feedback about it! I've recently read that escaping is not allowed :| . How about just put the special letters naturally? Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the "feed type" to "product" instead of "online product inventory update"? There has been a change since 2015.

Comment: How can I change it ? Is it in the feed (a parameter?) I can't see it

Comment: this should be at the place where you have registered your feed prior to uploading

Comment: Ok so now, the feed import is newer than 2015, so it should be ok.

Comment: No, the other way around: If the import is newer than 2015, the "feed type" might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<identifier_exists>FALSE</identifier_exists>
```

should be

```
<g:identifier_exists>false</g:identifier_exists>
```

also you have excessive CDATA usage. I don't have any in my XML and it works jut fine. try to submit file without CDATA`s